# $r$-cycle to a power $k$ is also an $r$-cycle if and only if $\gcd(k, r) = 1$

Tags: group-theory, permutations, cyclic-groups

Let $\sigma$ be an $r$-cycle in $S_n$ and let $k\in\Bbb Z$. Show that $\sigma^k$ is also an $r$-cycle if and only if $\gcd(k,r)=1$.

Comment: Tell us where you're having trouble. Do you know what an $r$-cycle is? Have you tried raising, say, a 6-cycle to different powers to see what happens? It's an if-and-only-if question: can you do one part, but not the other? Try to meet us halfway. Some people here like to close questions that don't show any effort from the person posting them.

Comment: Ok that's fair...I think given that sigma is an r cycle, and sigma^k is an r-cycle as well, then if gcd(k,r)=d, d>1, then sigma^k is actually (r/d) rather than r, but I can't quite explain it. 
Going the other way, if gcd(k,r)=1 and sigma is an r-cycle, then sigma^k can only get back to the start in lcm(r, k) permutations, i.e. rk permutations, so sigma^(rk) gets you back to the start so sigma is an r-cycle??
I just can't quite find the words, like logically it makes sense but that's as far as I can get!

Comment: For the harder part, suppose $\gcd(k,r)=1$. Then (Bezout) there are integers $x$ and $y$ such that $kx+ry=1$. We can take $x\ge 0$. Then $\sigma=\sigma^1=\sigma^{kx+ry}=(\sigma^k)^x(\sigma^r)^y=(\sigma^k)^x$. So the powers of $\sigma^k$ are the same as the powers of $\sigma$.

Comment: But you've now shown that $(\sigma^k)^x$ equals $\sigma$, but that doesn't mean $(\sigma^k)^r$ necessarily equals $\sigma$ does it??

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\left\langle \sigma^{k}\right\rangle =\left\langle\sigma^{gcd\left(k,r\right)}\right\rangle$, $ord\left(\sigma\right)=r$.