# Understanding hint in "$r$-cycle to a power $k$ is also an $r$-cycle iff $\gcd(k,r)=1$"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, permutations, permutation-cycles

I need help understanding hint in the answer to this question:
[$r$-cycle to a power $k$ is also an $r$-cycle if and only if $\gcd(k, r) = 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126971/r-cycle-to-a-power-k-is-also-an-r-cycle-if-and-only-if-gcdk-r-1?rq=1). The third comment also seems to be the same hint.

The hint also appears here: [Powers of $m$-cycles are also $m$-cycles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2037838/powers-of-m-cycles-are-also-m-cycles)

To be clear, the hint seems to be that if $\gcd(k,r)=1$, then $\langle \sigma^k \rangle=\langle \sigma \rangle$.

I know why the hint is true. It is because for any group $G$, if $|x|=r$ then $|x^k|=\frac{r}{\gcd(r,k)}$. Indeed, this fact immediately shows that if $\gcd(k,r)>1$, then $\sigma^k$ is not an $r$-cycle since it has order strictly less than $r$ and $r$-cycles have order $r$.

Conversely, suppose $\gcd(k,r)=1$.
What I don't understand is how knowing $\langle \sigma^k \rangle=\langle \sigma \rangle$ helps show that $\sigma^k$ is an $r$-cycle? I've already seen the solution where one shows that $\sigma^k(i)=i+k\pmod r$, but this hint I'm not understanding seems to lead to different solution which somehow avoids this computation.

Comment: I would not use the hints and just show what the cycle representation $\sigma^k$ is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the contrapositive. If $\sigma^k$ is not an $r$-cycle, then it is the product of shorter cycles, and there are an $i\in\operatorname{dom}\sigma$ and an integer $\ell$ such that $2\le\ell<r$ and $(\sigma^k)^\ell(i)=i$. But then the identity permutation and $(\sigma^k)^\ell$ are distinct members of $\langle\sigma^k\rangle$ sending $i$ to $i$, while $\langle\sigma\rangle$ clearly does not have a non-identity permutation that fixes $i$. Thus, $\langle\sigma^k\rangle\ne\langle\sigma\rangle$.

Comment: Thank you, this clarified things. I suppose if one wants to explicitly show that the identity is the only permutation in $\langle \sigma  \rangle$ that fixes $i$, one still has to use the computation $\sigma^j(i)=i+j\pmod r$.

Comment: @Lilypad: You’re welcome. Yes, you’d probably have to do something like that.

Comment: You can use `\rm` for `\operatorname`.

Comment: @ChrisCuster: [Not really](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48459/whats-the-difference-between-mathrm-and-operatorname/48463).

Comment: Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this isn't the answer you're looking for, but it might be illuminating to look at concrete examples.

Let $\sigma = (123456)$, then $\sigma^2  = (135)(246)$, and $\sigma^3 = (14)(25)(36)$.

But on the other hand $\sigma^5 = (165432)$ is also a $6$-cycle.

The fact that the power is coprime to the length of the cycle, prevents any possibilities of "loops".

Hopefully the hint makes more sense.